# Checking value of Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a submit button here:

```
submit_btn = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
submit_btn.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

and as soon as you click it, it should check the entry field above if the input == "Vincent".

This is the entry field:

```py
top = Tk()
user_label = Label(top, text="User Name")
user_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
username = Entry(top, bd = 5)
username.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Is there a way to check if the value of the 'username' Entry object is "Vincent"?

Comment: You may want to consider changing your variable naming scheme. Take a look at the [naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) in PEP 8.

Comment: And as you surely know, Tkinter's documentation is pretty crummy. Check out effbot's [tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/). It's quite helpful for questions like these (for example, ["The Tkinter Entry Widget"](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick.

```py
submit_btn = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=check_vincent)

def check_vincent():
    if username.get() == "Vincent":
        print "Hi, Vincent!"
    else:
        print "Where's Vincent?"
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. For some reason it wont print anything

Comment: You're probably just in-lining it with your code. Which, unless E1 is initialized with the text "Vincent," will never do anything (it checks once, moves on with your code, and is done). A callback function will be called each time your button is clicked. I added a basic example of a callback function. Try that.

Comment: OK that worked. I renamed all the Es and Ls and gave them proper names . Thanks

Comment: My pleasure (and nice work on the naming conventions). Again, I highly recommend reading the effbot tkinterbook. It will help you navigate Tkinter's quirks and sparse documentation.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I had to wait 10 minutes to accept it. Thanks again